# Mathematical life of Friedrich Ulmer

Tags: ct.category-theory, ho.history-overview

In the little galaxy of Category Theory, *Friedrich Ulmer* is known for being one of the authors of **Lokal Präsentierbare Kategorien**, a book that laid the foundations for the theory of locally presentable categories.

Unlike his coauthor, Pierre Gabriel, we do not have much information about him, or at least I can't find much.

- From the Genealogy Project we know that he did his PhD in Zürich in 1964 under *Dold* and *van der Waerden*.
- According to Scopus, we only have 7 documents by Ulmer, even though other documents can be found with a bit of struggle on the internet. With a bit of help from google and semanticscholar we find a couple of more entrencies. zbMath lists a total of 12 publications by Ulmer.

I can't find a complete bibliography of his, nor I can tell whether he spent his life in Academia or outside of it.

Does anybody have better luck then me? Or happens to have more information? What I was looking for is something like [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404996001582) or [this one](https://www.ams.org/notices/199810/mem-eilenberg.pdf). Of course, there might be nothing more to say.

Comment: I am sorry, but did you even look on MathReviews? https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/author.html?mrauthid=557104 - 12 items authored by him.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. For some reason, MathSciNet never works on my computer since a couple of years, and I really cannot understand why. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure for how long and where you looked, but it takes less than 30 minutes to figure much more than you mention in your post. Apparently, he continued his academic career as Fritz Ulmer : if you look at the affiliation of the last indexed MathReviews paper

- *Localizations of endomorphism rings and fixpoints*, Journal of Algebra **43** Issue 2 (1976) Pages 529–551, https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(76)90125-3,

you see that he was in Wuppertal, and then a quick Google search shows that "Fritz Ulmer = Friedrich Ulmer":

1. Look at https://idw-online.de/de/news52962 and examine the part "Kontakt",
   and
2. Look at https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Fritz-Ulmer .

The website http://www.wahlprognosen-info.de/ seems to contain some of his interviews on matters of statistics etc., see http://www.wahlprognosen-info.de/index2.htm?/archiv/BB7.htm .